# How to properly store data into database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm facing a very simple problem, but I don't know how to solve it. I have a simple textBox, and local database, `Database1.mdf`, with one table: emp. Inserting data works fine, but when I restart application, then these data are lost.

I'm also using a dataSet, where I can see data in the table - the record is properly inserted, but it is lost when I restart the app. What am I missing?

I'm running a C# application (VS2013):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::base.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);
    try {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO emp (name) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "')";
        SqlCommand exesql = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
        cn.Open();
        exesql.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Hooray!!");
        this.empTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.emp);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: On restarting application, I hope you are not creating the database again. Please verify that there is no check being done at the start which deletes the database if it already exists on starting the application.

Comment: I'm pretty newbie. How can I check that?

Comment: You must have written code to initialize the database or something. No? Debug the application starting from the first line of Main() and see where exactly you are interacting with the database.

Comment: Look for it in app.config file.. or search for any query that looks like "Delete if exists..."

Comment: Aside: You are asking for a visit from [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). Using parameters in queries is the way to go.

Comment: Your Visual Studio will copy a new, fresh database into your debug directory whenever you start your application. I have no clue how to change this, as I have never used the non-server versions of MSSql.

Comment: Set Database1.mdf's "Copy to Output Directory" property value to "Do not copy" from Properties box

Comment: @HABO: I understand that problem. But I tried to avoid "unnecessary" code to solve my problem.

Comment: @Avijit: thanks, that solved my problem. Feel free to submit the answer and I shall accept, appreciate the help

Comment: Out of the scope of this question : Beware of the SQL Injection attack for which your code is not proof. Read why and how here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Database1.mdf's "Copy to Output Directory" property value to "Do not copy" from Properties box.